# How does Tensorflow 2.0 AutoGraph handle numpy operation?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Apparently TF2.0 Autograph works with Numpy operations

I wrote a simple example below and I use `autograph.to_code` to see what Autograph does with the Numpy operation. The `ag__.converted_call` seems to do the work of running Numpy functions. But I don't know what happens under this converted call.

I am curious how TF generated the graph with Numpy operations. Does TF2.0 convert all Numpy operations into TF ops? Do we need to worry about the performance issue by over-using Numpy operation in our TF2.0 code?

```
@tf.function
def run():

    a = np.array([1, 2])
    if a[0] > 1:
        a[0] = 10
        a = a.reshape(-1)
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(a)

print(tf.autograph.to_code(run.python_function))
```

This gives the output:

```
def tf__run():
  do_return = False
  retval_ = ag__.UndefinedReturnValue()
  with ag__.FunctionScope('run', 'run_scope', ag__.ConversionOptions(recursive=True, user_requested=True, optional_features=(), internal_convert_user_code=True)) as run_scope:
    a = ag__.converted_call(np.array, run_scope.callopts, ([1, 2],), None, run_scope)

    def get_state():
      return a[0],

    def set_state(vals):
      a[0], = vals

    def if_true():
      a_1, = a,
      a_1[0] = 10
      a_1 = ag__.converted_call(a_1.reshape, run_scope.callopts, (-1,), None, run_scope)
      return a_1

    def if_false():
      return a
    cond = a[0] > 1
    a = ag__.if_stmt(cond, if_true, if_false, get_state, set_state, ('a',), ('a[0]',))
    do_return = True
    retval_ = run_scope.mark_return_value(ag__.converted_call(tf.convert_to_tensor, run_scope.callopts, (a,), None, run_scope))
  do_return,
  return ag__.retval(retval_)
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [Better performance with tf.function guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function).

> tf.function works best with TensorFlow ops; NumPy and Python calls are converted to constants.

Using TensorFlow ops is recommended. Moreover, while mixing NumPy and TensorFlow ops can work in eager mode, when you enable tf.function you can run into errors.

If you want to use NumPy ops you can try out the [tf.experimental.numpy API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tf_numpy).